# Como integrar Jquery.validator e plugin SmartNotification.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Como eu integro as mensagens do Jquery.Validator() com as janelas modais do plugin SmartNotification.js? Gostaria que, quando os *inputs* entrarem nas *roles* dos *validators* do JQuery seja exibida uma mensagem via SmartNotification.js. Eu não estou conseguindo integrar os dois para fazer uma validação de *forms* — em outras palavras fazer um "crud" padronizado.

Segue meu exemplo de função do SmartNotification.js é só ela ser chamada pelo Jquery.Validator():

```
function PrintAlert(alert) {
    $.SmartMessageBox({
        title: '<i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Aviso!',
        content: '<div style="margin:10px 0px 0px 5px;">' + alert + '</div>',
        buttons: '[Voltar]'
    });
}
```

Jquery.Validator que quero implementar de exemplo:

```
jQuery('.myform').validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 5
        },
        password_confirm: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 5,
              equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
```

Como implemento, eu tentei mas quando surgia a mensagem do SmartNotification.js mesmo clicando no botão voltar que surge ela não saia entendem ficava na tela tentei colocar `return (false)` e nada, creio que exista algum jeito.

Segue um exemplo da modal do SmartNotification.js :

[image]
Obrigado desde já quem tiver um exemplo ou puder ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que li na [documentação do plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/) `.validate()` tens um método/callback para quando o validate passa e quando não passa. Respectivamente [`submitHandler`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/#submithandler) e [`invalidhandler`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/#invalidhandler)

O `submitHandler` corre uma função passando a `form` como argumento:

```
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // tudo ok! submeter
    form.submit();
  }
```

Aí tens de escolher uma frase para passar para o *SmartNotification.js*.

O `` corre uma função passando o evento e o a instância do `validator` para essa form. Essa função passa também a `form` no `this`. Aqui podes ir buscar o numero de erros com `validator.numberOfInvalids();`.

```
invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
    // 'this' refere-se à form
    var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
}
```

Assim podias fazer algo como:

```
jQuery('.myform').validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        password_confirm: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
        var erros = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        var singularPlural = erros > 1 ? 'erros' : 'erro';
        var mensagem = ['Tem', erros, singularPlural, 'no fomulário. Por favor complete'].join(' ');
        PrintAlert(mensagem);
        // e aqui podes aplicar estilos à form via por exemplo $(this).css(etc..., etc...);
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        PrintAlert('tudo ok! formulário será submetido.');
        form.submit();
    }
});
```